# Как правильно организовать базу данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Знатоки БД подскажите пожалуйста. Предположим у нас есть Таблица заказов, заказ имеет примерно вот такой вид

```json
{
  id: string
  products: any[]
  ...
}
```

Нужно сделать так что бы к заказу можно было оставлять несколько разных по смыслу сообщений назавем их **clientMessage, note, inscription, deliveryMessage**. Как будет правильнее организовать это в базе данных? У меня получаются вот такие варианты:

1. Наиболее не удобный как по мне вариант, просто добавить к таблице новые столбцы. В заказе еще очень много данных и все сообщения хотелось бы сложить в отделбную сущность.

```json
{
  id: string
  products: any[]
  clientMssage: string
  note: string
  inscription: string
  deliveryMessage: string
  ...
}
```

2. Вариант более удобный но сложно поддерживаемый, сделать отдельный столбец с типом данных JSON или JSOB, и все сообщения складывать туда

```json
{
  id: string
  products: any[]
  messages : {
    clientMssage: string
    note: string
    inscription: string
    deliveryMessage: string
  }
  ...
}
```

3. Последний вариант который пришел мне в голову, созадть отдельную таблицу orderMessages, и настроить свзь одной таблицы с другой.

Скажите какой вариант по вашему мнению лучше, или может вообще сделать как то по другому?

Comment: Конечно, 3-й вариант самый правильный, если речь о реляционных БД и вам нужно делать какие-то выборки по данным из доп. таблицы, а не просто их хранить.